# htaccess with multiple parameters

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?Action=$2&id=$3
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?Action=$2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Here is my `.htaccess`. However only the first `RewriteRule` works. If I comment out other rules, the others left work fine, but they don't work together. What I want is the clean URL with multiple parameters.

I don't have any clue of this problem. I Googled a lot and all the information I've found says the same as my code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain your RewriteRules using the C flag, as explained on the ServerFault page [Everything You Ever Wanted to Know about Mod_Rewrite Rules but Were Afraid to Ask?](https://serverfault.com/questions/214512/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know-about-mod-rewrite-rules-but-were-afraid-to-as)

In your case, this would do:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?Action=$2&id=$3 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ $1.php?Action=$2 [C]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks... but Still can't work out with C flag

Comment: Hi. finally it's working with flag [L].... thanks anyways.
.htaccess is always headache, isn't it?

Comment: Hi, good to hear you got it working. Please answer your own question by posting the correct .htaccess, so others can learn from your situation.

Comment: Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /api/$1.php?Action=$2&id=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /api/$1.php?Action=$2 [L]

Answer (score 0):

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.php$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ /api/$1.php?Action=$2&id=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)$ /api/$1.php?Action=$2 [L]
```

With [L] flag, my htaccess started working fine.